# PayPal Android SDK - INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Tags: android, paypal, sdk, internal-server-error

I currently try to include the new PayPal SDK but if i try to do a payment (LIVE or SANDBOX) i always get the following error:

```
01-23 21:07:20.295: E/RequestError(22408): 500 http response received.  Response not parsable.
01-23 21:07:20.295: E/PayPalService(22408): INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
01-23 21:07:20.335: E/LoginActivity(22408): login error: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
01-23 21:07:20.375: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22408): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-23 21:07:20.375: E/RichInputConnection(1056): Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text... will retry later
01-23 21:07:20.385: W/InputMethodManagerService(773): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@42ee5620 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@4451e2b8
01-23 21:07:20.675: W/System.err(22408): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:146)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at com.paypal.android.sdk.bu.a(Unknown Source)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at com.paypal.android.sdk.bu.run(Unknown Source)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-23 21:07:20.685: W/System.err(22408):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-23 21:07:20.685: E/class java.net.ConnectException(22408): java.net.ConnectException
```

Anyone has an idea how i can fix this. Or what's causing this issue?

Thanks!

i still get the following error:

```
02-08 14:18:04.344: E/RequestError(21818): 500 http response received.  Response not parsable.
02-08 14:18:04.344: E/PayPalService(21818): INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
02-08 14:18:04.394: E/LoginActivity(21818): login error: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

No-one with similar issues?

Comment: Did you get this issue fixed?

Comment: not yet :/ i hope someone has another issue so i can publish this

Comment: Thanks, I have a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549106/paypal-android-sdk-login-failed-system-error-please-try-again-later-intern and on the Android PayPal SDK https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/46. I have also created a technical support request and someone is looking into it right now.

Comment: ok thank you. if you get an answer would you be so kind to help me here too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in PayPal login window, which incorrectly parses or sends the credentials. I had the same issue, when my password contained `&` character. When I changed my password not to contain `&` character, the issue disappeared.

The same issue is describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549106/paypal-android-sdk-login-failed-system-error-please-try-again-later-intern) and in the [PayPal Android SDK GitHub issues](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/46).

Comment: Thank you. Did you get any infos from paypal itself if or when they will fix this issue?

Comment: I am in contact with technical support guys at the moment. They usually respond quite fast, so I hope I will get "official" explanation tomorrow or Tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the receiver email that matches up with the clientID you are specifying.  If that's not the issue for you, I'd recommend filing a ticket at http://www.paypal.com/mts so that some specific account information can be gathered and the issue researched further.

Comment: no it did not change the problem.

I've added another log-output to my question. perhaps you have another tipp? I wrote an e-mail already but got no answer.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in release 2.0.0 of the [PayPal-Android-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/releases).  Special characters in user passwords are now handled properly.