# why am I getting paypal system error please try again

Tags: android, paypal

I am trying to integrate payapal into my mobile app. I have been following [this tutorial](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md) that I found. But when I try to make a payment I get an error saying Login failed: System error. Please try again. I'm not sure what the problem is. My login information is correct so I know that's not the problem. Can I get some help about this. Thanks in advance. Here is my code by the way

```
 //Main activity

      private static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE=7171;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config=new PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
            .clientId(Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_in_one);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fragment_close_exit, R.anim.fragment_fade_enter);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.black));


        //start paypal service
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        startService(intent);
        

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation=data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if(confirmation!=null){
                    try {
                        String paymentDetails=confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, PayPalPaymentDetails.class).
                                putExtra("Payment Details",paymentDetails)
                                .putExtra("Amount","5.00")
                        );

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }else if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if(resultCode==PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your password in the PayPal login contains "&", this error occurs. Make sure that you do not use that character in your password.

The same issue has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549106/paypal-android-sdk-login-failed-system-error-please-try-again-later-intern).

Comment: I found this useful